# Derivative of polynomial division in Maple

Tags: derivatives, maple

This is proably a beginner's question about Maple.  I'm trying to use Maple to differentiate:

$$\frac{(z^2-1)^2}{(az-1)(z-a)}$$

Where $a$ is a constant.

[image]

- On the first line, is there a way to tell Maple not to expand the denominator?
- How can you tell Maple that $z$ is variable and $a$ is constant?
- On the second line, what does Maple mean with $D(az)$ ?
- The differential seems to be missing the term with $(z^2-1)^2 (az-1)$ in the numerator?

Any hints or pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type out $a*z$ instead of $az$. Maple thinks, $az$ is another variable.
Also
$$(z^2 - 1)^2/((a*z-1)*(z-a))$$
Will give the desired output. This pretty much fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks!  Say you omit the $*$ between two brackets, for example $(a*z-1)(z-a)$.  Maple turns this into $a(z-a)z(z-a)-1$.  What's up with that?

Comment: Probably, Maple thinks the second brackets are "arguments" and the first are a composed function (f(x) = a(x)*z(x) - 1)...

Comment: Whoah.  Implicit variable/function definition seems error prone!  Is there some kind of "safe mode" that requires you to declare variables and functions explicitly?

Comment: It also works if you use spaces instead of explicit `*` or `.` to denote the multiplication. But implicit denotation of multiplication has problem cases, because of round brackets serving double duty as both grouping delimiters and function call argument delimiters. These problems are not rare. You are using 2D Math input mode, but you can switch to 1D plaintext Maple Notation as default, which demands explicit code. See Tools->Options->Display->Input display. Also try Tools->Options->Interface-Default format for new worksheets set to Worksheet instead of Document, if only while a new user.

Comment: @acer: So that's what 2D vs 1D input mode is about!  Awesome.